# Laravel 5.1 url value not passing to controller PUT method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I have a simple form for updating book info.

```
<form action="{{ action('BookController@update') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

  <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="title" value="{{ $book[0]->title }}">

  <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control" name="author" placeholder="author" value="{{ $book[0]->author }}">
      ......................

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $book = new Book;

    $title      = $request->input('title');
    $author     = $request->input('author');
    $category   = $request->input('category');
    $date       = $request->input('date');

    if ($book->updateBook($id, $title, $author, $category, $date)) {
        return redirect('books')->with('status', 'Successfuly edited!');
    }
    else {
        return dd($id);
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't pass the right $id. It pass a string {books}

Basically `$id = "{books}"`

It should be an integer (31) from url `/books/31/edit`

In routes is defined as a resource with all available default methods
What can i do?

Comment: Please post the relevant line from your routes file.

Comment: It's a resource like so Route::resource('books', 'BookController')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the book's ID in the form definition, as the second argument to `action()`:

`<form action="{{ action('BookController@update', ['id' => $book[0]->id]) }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">`

See the [definition of `action()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-action) for more information.

Comment: But i don't have that value in the page.. Only in url.. I thought it should be passed automatically

Comment: That's just not what `action()` does. It takes arguments to fill the route parameters (like the book's ID).

If your edit page is already /books/1, you can try to leave the entire `action="..."`off the form definition. This should post back to the same URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple: i just needed to pass $id to the view and then pass it to form action as @EricMakesStuff suggested..

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<form action="{{ action('BookController@update', ['id'=> 1]) }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

Comment: Please explain the OP why he should try your solution.